# Disable linking to YouTube in an embedded video

Tags: youtube, embed

We want to use YouTube to share learning videos on our learning & development portal, however, we want these videos only to be watchable in said portal and not have the option to view these on YouTube, as that might distract our employees and be counterproductive to the learning experience.

Most of the information on this topic found is dated, I have added some examples of what we have tried:

1. Using attribute

```html
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px">
<param name="movie" value="blablabla?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<embed src="blablabla?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></object>
```

2. Appending `?modestbranding=1` parameter to the YouTube URL
3. Appending `allownetworking="internal"` to `allowfullscreen="true"`

Answer (score -1):

You can try using youtube's `unlisted video` feature. An unlisted video is a different type of private video. "Unlisted" means that only people who know the link to the video can view it (such as friends or family to whom you send the link). An unlisted video will not appear in any of YouTube's public spaces (such as search results, your channel, or the Browse page). An unlisted video is different from a private video in these ways.

1. Sign in to your YouTube Account
2. Go to your My Videos page
3. Select the video which you’d like to make an unlisted video. Click
   the Edit button to access the video’s settings.
4. Go to the Privacy section of the page. There you’ll see the option
   to mark you video as “unlisted”, “public”, or “private”. Select unlisted.
5. Click the Save Changes button. Once you’ve done this
   your video will be an unlisted video.

Make sure you want to do it because you have to maintain a youtube video link database for your reference, as your video list grows your database will grow. If you don't want to maintain the database manually, you can go for [Youtube API](http://Sign%20into%20your%20YouTube%20Account).

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the question is asking.